# Форматирование тега <input>

Tags: css, веб-программирование, веб-дизайн

Почему не все стили для `<input>` срабатывают, в частности `color`?

```css
.stay-input {
  background: none;
  width: 211px;
  height: 45px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" name="email-newsletter" placeholder="Subscribe our newsletter" class="stay-input">
</form>
```

Comment: Всё срабатывает — вы же цвет задали **белый**: `color: white;` :)

Comment: а по факту он не белый, а серый. И если задать любой другой (хоть красный) - ничего не меняется

Comment: Потому что вы стилизуете ввод, а не подсказку (`placeholder`).

Comment: точно, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Потому что вы видимо хотите стилизовать `placeholder`

```css
.stay-input {
  background: none;
  width: 211px;
  height: 45px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#c0392b;}
::-moz-placeholder          {color:#c0392b;}/* Firefox 19+ */
:-moz-placeholder           {color:#c0392b;}/* Firefox 18- */
:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:#c0392b;}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" name="email-newsletter" placeholder="Subscribe our newsletter" class="stay-input">
</form>
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо!!